# Make PHP script editable & pulling data from SQL table

Tags: php, html

I have create Table in HTML & converted it to PHP using online tool. Below is part of the coding & image of the table. Now i want to make the textbox editable and display data from sql table. How can i do that?

[image: Table image]

```
 print "    <td class=\"tg-7btt\">U</td>\n";
 print "    <td class=\"tg-fymr\"><W/td>\n";
 print "    <td class=\"tg-fymr\">X</td>\n";
 print "    <td class=\"tg-fymr\">Y</td>\n";
 print "    <td class=\"tg-fymr\">Z</td>\n";
 print "  </tr>\n";
 print "  <tr>\n";
 print "    <td class=\"tg-fymr\">Planned Execution Metrics</td>\n";
 print "    <td class=\"tg-c3ow\" colspan=\"5\"></td>\n";
 print "  </tr>\n";
 print "  <tr>\n";
 print "    <td class=\"tg-0pky\">Total planned Test Cases</td>\n";
 print "    <td class=\"tg-c3ow\"></td>\n";
 print "    <td class=\"tg-0pky\"></td>\n";
 print "    <td class=\"tg-0pky\"></td>\n";
 print "    <td class=\"tg-0pky\"></td>\n";
 print "    <td class=\"tg-0pky\"></td>\n";
 print "  </tr>\n";
```

Comment: one of the ways you can use an `<input>` text box

Comment: @ghost can you show me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Use `input` inside the `td` and display the sql data inside the `value` attr of the input

Answer (score 0):

why do need textbox you can do it directly from the code below

```
<div class="tables">
<table class="table"> <thead> <tr> <th>Id</th> <th>Message</th> <th>Date</th> <th>Exipry date</th>  <th> Actions </th> <th> &nbsp </th> </tr> </thead> 
<tbody> 
<?php
 $sql="select * from notice";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr class='active'> 
        <td>".$row[0]."</td> 
        <td>".$row[1]."</td> 
        <td>".$row[2]."</td> 
        <td>".$row[3]."</td>
        </tr>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\crustest\table.php on line 3

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\crustest\table.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\crustest\table.php on line 3

Comment: I have  changed the answer you can this @Greeny